# Previous line repeat while stepping through code execution

Tags: c++, instantiation

While stepping through my code, I have noticed that when confronted with instantiating a new class, the code steps back a line thus executing it twice. 
Here are the two lines.

```
ST_GalacticObject GO = GalacticObjects->Item [FIndex];
delete F; F = new ST_Facility (GO);
```

NOTE:
Both GalacticObjects and a related object (same file) known as FacilityClasses are defined as extern.

Comment: The constructor is not in fact executed twice. The observed behaviour of the debugger is misleading.

Comment: The question is missing the name of the debugger...

Answer (score 1):

There are many hidden bits of generated code when creating and destroying objects.

The compiler assigned some line number to this code when it created it. When the code is executed the debugger highlights that line.

One common case is the debugger goes back to the line an object was declared on when running the destructor.

This gets even worse with optimised code when your code wont necessarily be executed in order and you might even see lines getting executed multiple times as different parts of each line are evaluated.

You just have to trust that the compiler has done the right thing and generated the correct code and ignore what the debugger is telling you is going on.

Answer (score 0):

These types of things are common when debugging optimized (retail) code.

But the most obvious improvement you can make so the debugger isn't confused is to not put two statements on the same line.  That is, instead of this:

```
delete F; F = new ST_Facility (GO);
```

This:

```
delete F; 
F = new ST_Facility (GO);
```

Newer compilers have introduced options to generate better (and larger) debugging symbols that try to make the step-through process a bit more sane for optimized code.  If you are on Visual Studio, you could explore the `/Zo` option (formerly the `/d2Zi+` option).  Details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zo-enhance-optimized-debugging?view=vs-2019) and [here](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/debugging-optimized-codenew-in-visual-studio-2012/).

But if all of this is your own code, just switch to building as "debug" and/or "non-optimized".  Makes life a whole lot easier.